# How do I integrate MongoDB with Solr?

Tags: php, mongodb, solr

I've seen this question before, but it's never received a real answer- so I was wondering.. Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I can integrate mongoDB with Solr? I'm looking for pseudo real-time and eventual consistency.

Can anyone that's done this shed some light?

I'm also using PHP/Zend with Doctrine Mongo if that helps.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't done any integration, and I'm sure you've already googled, but...

http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/383437318/integrating-mongodb-with-solr

http://blog.knuthaugen.no/2010/04/cooking-with-mongodb-and-solr.html

The issue you are probably going to run into with a "psuedo real-time" solution, depending on your volume, is performance. Solr performance with high commits isn't the greatest. In other words, its not really so much of a real-time indexing solution as it is a batch indexing solution. Depending on what you're actually doing this may or may not be an issue for you.

[ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) (mentioned above) has been making a lot of noise in the blogosphere lately and it has a JSON api, so you might want to look at it if you're using MongoDB. I've run across [these performance metrics](http://engineering.socialcast.com/2011/05/realtime-search-solr-vs-elasticsearch/) when doing some research on real-time commits (I've never used ElasticSearch, though).

AFAIK, there is only one (highly dedicated) contributor to ElasticSearch.

Comment: Thanks, I saw those already - ATM What i'm going to do it tail the oplog using tailable cursors, and update the index when the DB get's updated. Doesn't seem like the most efficient method given that as you said, Solr is bad at realtime commits, but it'll do for now.